# Multiple Binding and Contextual Binding with Ninject and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ninject

- I have an `Interface` which take data from local `Json` file on startup (Deserialized)
  This Interface is Injected to 3 Features
- With `Contextual Name Binding`, all 3 Features run correctly as I expected with 3 different device config from local json file
- When I want my `MainView` to display the settings of all 3 devices, I have to take all 3 Bindings and inject them into `MainViewModel` as the code below
- The problem is `MainViewModel` gets nothing from the kernel because I used `.WhenParentNamed(devicename)` on binding DeviceConfig, when I remove this, the kernel did return 3 instances in array
- I Wonder if there is any way I can get all DeviceConfig Instance Without removing `WhenParentNamed` Contextual Binding. This is my first online question so sorry for my bad English and thanks for reading!!

```
public interface IDeviceConfig 
{
    int Param1 {get;set;}
    int Param2 {get;set;}
    ...

}
```

```
internal class DeviceConfig : IDeviceConfig
{
    int Param1
    {

    }

    int Param2
    {

    }
...
}
```

```
public sealed partial class App : Application
{
     var kernel = new StandardKernel();

     var AllDevices = GetDeviceConfigFromJson();
     if (AllDevices.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < AllDevices.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var devicename = i.ToString();

                        kernel.Bind<IDeviceConfig>().ToConstant(AllDevices.ElementAt(i)).WhenParentNamed(devicename);
                        kernel.Bind<IFeature1>().To<Feature1>().Named(devicename);
                        kernel.Bind<IFeature2>().To<Feature2>().Named(devicename);
                        kernel.Bind<IFeature3>().To<Feature3>().Named(devicename);
                        //Each device has 3 features and all 3 features get property from DeviceConfig


                        //on startup all device get config and run
                        kernel.Get<IFeature1>(devicename);
                        kernel.Get<IFeature2>(devicename);
                        kernel.Get<IFeature3>(devicename);
                    }
                }
     kernel.Bind<MainViewModel>.ToSelf();

     Current.MainWindow = kernel.Get<MainView>();
     Current.MainWindow.Show();
     
    
}
```

```
public MainViewViewModel(IDeviceConfig[] devices)
        {
           ShowAllDevices(devices); // Mainview Binding Xaml to each Device's Config
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found an ugly way but it works!

```
kernel.Bind<IDeviceConfig>.ToConstant(AllDevices.ElementAt(i)).Named(devicename);
kernel.Bind<IFeature1>().To<Feature1>().InSingletonScope().WithConstructorArgument("config", kernel.Get<IDeviceConfig>(devicename))Named(devicename);

 var feature1 = kernel.Get<IFeature1>(devicename);
```